# Can't use prophet for forecasting ( Dataframe has less than 2 non-NaN rows)

Tags: python, facebook-prophet

[My notebook in kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/jefferywong0f23/prophet-success?scriptVersionId=6356493)

Please focus on the block near the bottom of my notebook. I can't do a forecast with an error message "ValueError: Dataframe has less than 2 non-NaN rows."

**What Can I do to resolve it ???**

```
tic = time.time()

for s in proph_results['shop_id'].unique():
    for i in proph_results['item_id'].unique():
        proph_train = train.loc[(train['shop_id'] == s) & (train['item_id'] == i)].reset_index()
        proph_train.rename(columns={'date': 'ds', 'item_cnt_day': 'y'}, inplace=True)

        m = Prophet()
        m.fit(proph_train[['ds', 'y']])
        future = m.make_future_dataframe(periods=len(test_old.index.unique()), include_history=False)
        fcst = m.predict(future)

        proph_results.loc[(proph_results['shop_id'] == s) & (proph_results['item_id'] == i), 'sales'] = fcst['yhat'].values

        toc = time.time()
        if i % 10 == 0:
            print("Completed store {} item {}. Cumulative time: {:.1f}s".format(s, i, toc-tic))
```

Answer (score 7):

`Prophet` cannot be used when number of rows (which are not null) in the data  you're passing is less than 2. So, you cannot do the prediction in that case.

So you get an error when you're fitting the model.

There's no other solution other than adding more (not null) data to the existing.

Comment: Maybe you should take a look at [How to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) and be careful with the formatting and excessive exclamation points, for example. Also, brief answers can be good but they need some strong points.

Comment: similar issues i am facing but i did not do the looping model.fit. can you please some one help